# setspace kill the \flushbottom, how to make the sep between footnote item equal that in normal text

Tags: vertical-alignment, footnotes, setspace

I want double spacing, but then sep between footnote item is strange. I use `setspace` package, but it kill the `\flushbottom` mechanism.

Is there a method after I set \linespread{2}, the footnote text area have no other difference with normal text area, just like a `\footnotesize` declaration insert into?

Anyway, here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\linespread{2}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
abc\footnote{murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur} def\footnote{murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDEiV.jpg). I am not satisfied with the sep between the two footnotes. I want they could be [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF7jL.jpg).

If I use `setspace`, the bottom of page is ragged. It's too ugly. There are the samples (please compare the output, especially bottom of page 1)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[width=5in,height=8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
%\linespread{1.667}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\flushbottom
\newcommand{\MY}{\dfrac{1+\dfrac{\sum}{\sum}}{\dfrac{\sum}{\sum}+1}}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{1pt plus0.1pt minus0.1pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{1pt plus0.1pt minus0.1pt}
\lipsum[2]
\[\MY\]

\lipsum[2]
\[\MY\]

\lipsum[2]
\[\MY\]

\lipsum[2]
\[\MY\]
\end{document}



\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[width=5in,height=8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{setspace}
%\doublespacing
\linespread{1.667}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\flushbottom
\newcommand{\MY}{\dfrac{1+\dfrac{\sum}{\sum}}{\dfrac{\sum}{\sum}+1}}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{1pt plus0.1pt minus0.1pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{1pt plus0.1pt minus0.1pt}
\lipsum[2]
\[\MY\]

\lipsum[2]
\[\MY\]

\lipsum[2]
\[\MY\]

\lipsum[2]
\[\MY\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there no one think that it is an obstacle?

Answer (score 1):

use package `setspace`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{footmisc}
\renewcommand\footnotelayout{\doublespacing}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
abc\footnote{murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur} def\footnote{murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur murmur}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Herbert: but the area of footnote is not doublespacing...

Comment: @Rushavski: see edited example.

Comment: what do you mean with paste?

Comment: @Herbert: please compare the code below: `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{lipsum} \usepackage[width=5in,height=8in]{geometry} \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{setspace} \doublespacing % \linespread{1.667} \usepackage{footmisc} \setlength{\parskip}{0pt} \flushbottom \newcommand{\MY}{\dfrac{1+\dfrac{\sum}{\sum}}{\dfrac{\sum}{\sum}+1}} \begin{document} \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{1pt plus0.1pt minus0.1pt} \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{1pt plus0.1pt minus0.1pt} \lipsum[2] \[\MY\] \lipsum[2] \[\MY\] \lipsum[2] \[\MY\] \lipsum[2] \[\MY\] \end{document}`

Comment: @Herbert: `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{lipsum} \usepackage[width=5in,height=8in]{geometry} \usepackage{amsmath} % \usepackage{setspace} % \doublespacing \linespread{1.667} \usepackage{footmisc} \setlength{\parskip}{0pt} \flushbottom \newcommand{\MY}{\dfrac{1+\dfrac{\sum}{\sum}}{\dfrac{\sum}{\sum}+1}} \begin{document} \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{1pt plus0.1pt minus0.1pt} \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{1pt plus0.1pt minus0.1pt} \lipsum[2] \[\MY\] \lipsum[2] \[\MY\] \lipsum[2] \[\MY\] \lipsum[2] \[\MY\] \end{document}`notice the bottom of page 1.

Comment: @Herbert: I mean if I use `setspace` package, it will kill the `\fulshbottom` command.